# $A, B$ and $C$ are sets with $A\times B=A\times C$. For which sets $A$ it follows $B=C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For which sets $A$  does it follow that if $A\times B=A\times C$ then  $B=C$?

I must prove that there are some sets $A$ that shows that $B=C$.
I really don't know where to start.

Comment: This is true whenever $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: I thought so too, but I must prove it in some kind of way, and I don't know how to start the proof.

Comment: If $(a,b)\in A\times B$ and $A\times B=A\times C$ then $(a,b)\in A\times C$ so $b\in C$. That is, $B\subseteq C$. And symmetrically, $C\subseteq B$. By the way, you do mean *equality* of sets, right? You don't just mean to say they're equinumerous? (Because it's certainly possible for $|A\times B|=|A\times C|$ while $|B|\ne |C|$.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $A \times B =A \times C$ and $a \in A$ then 
$$\{ a \} \times B \subset A \times B=A \times C$$

This implies that $B \subset C$. Same way you get $C \subset B$:

**Details:** Let $b \in B$. Then $(a,b) \in A \times B= A \times C$. Since $(a,b) \in A \times C$ we get by definition that $b \in C$.

Therefore, **as long as you can pick some $a \in A$** you can prove $B=C$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do you show that the expression you wrote implies that B is a subset of C?

Comment: @Ergo Added details.